# No module named 'requests' when pip installing ssh-import-id

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I'm using Heroku as a development server. When I try to push my Django application to Heroku it first tries to install my packages from the `requirements.txt` file.

```
requests==2.18.3
ssh-import-id==5.5
```

The problem is I have a dependency on one of my packages with others. In the above packages, `ssh-import-id` needs `requests` package already installed. So when I push the app, pip fails to install and stops the deployment.

```
Collecting requests==2.18.3 (from -r re.txt (line 1))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/92/c35ed010e8f96781f08dfa6d9a6a19445a175a9304aceedece77cd48b68f/requests-2.18.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ssh-import-id==5.5 (from -r re.txt (line 2))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/cc/0a8662a2d2a781db546944f3820b9a3a1a664a47c000577b7fb4db2dfbf8/ssh-import-id-5.5.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-go0a5mxf/ssh-import-id/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ssh_import_id import __version__
  File "/tmp/pip-install-go0a5mxf/ssh-import-id/ssh_import_id/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-go0a5mxf/ssh-import-id/
```

I need to install all the listed packages using pip in single attempt. Because by default Heroku runs,  `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: This is probably a bug. Please report it. Meanwhile can you try removing requests from requirement file?

Comment: Here is a bug that is already tracking the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id/+bug/1696021. They've mentioned a fix in there but I think that's been added after 5.5.

Comment: This issue appears to only affect old versions of Python. You should set your runtime.txt to python-3.7.2.

Comment: @SuperShoot Updating Package from 5.5 to latest is also not working. Same issue

Comment: Does it have the exact same traceback? E.g. including this: `File "/tmp/pip-install-go0a5mxf/ssh-import-id/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ssh_import_id import __version__`

Comment: Yes, I have copied it from Heroku.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth Removing Requests also gives the same error

Comment: If it has that exact line in the traceback then you aren't using a version that contains the patch mentioned in the bug report. See [this commit](https://git.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id/commit/?id=08786c0a68a85d60700f025d79bbdffd725c34f1) on the master branch and notice how the `from ssh_import_id import __version__` line has been removed and replaced with a `read_version()` function.

Comment: From [here](https://pypi.org/project/ssh-import-id/) I have taken the latest version. But this also show the same error

Comment: Not fixed in 5.6: https://git.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id/tree/setup.py?id=bafec7df925a581c91fc6584c794adeb99b2eb08. You'd have to get the patched version from the repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190685/discussion-between-muthu-kumar-and-supershoot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id/+bug/1696021).

The library's `setup.py` imports the library to get the version for inclusion in the `setup()` function call...

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
from ssh_import_id import __version__
```

... and the library tries to import requests which doesn't yet exist in the environment. This is `ssh_import_id.__init__.py`:

```
import argparse
import json
import logging
import os
import platform
import requests  # <=== here
import stat
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
```

A fix has been added which works around needing to import the package to get the version...

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
import sys


def read_version():
    # shove 'version' into the path so we can import it without going through
    # ssh_import_id which has deps that wont be available at setup.py time.
    # specifically, from 'ssh_import_id import version'
    # will fail due to requests not available.
    verdir = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "ssh_import_id"))
    sys.path.insert(0, verdir)
    import version
    return version.VERSION
```

... but the fix isn't in the current pypi version 5.6.

You could install latest master branch from source instead of pypi by changing your requirements.txt to something like:

```
-e git+https://git.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id#egg=master
```